# ¿Cómo insertar datos correctamente en una base de datos?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, sqlite

Hola pues tengo una aplicación de contactos que se obtienen desde una tabla en una base de datos que además contiene el número de likes de cada contacto, tengo un ImageButton y al darle click se debe insertar un nuevo like en la tabla en el id de su respectivo contacto y un TextView que se actualiza mostrando la suma de likes, el problema es que funciona solo con el primer like, si presiono de nuevo el botón para dar like a un contacto me manda la siguiente excepción:

```
Error inserting numero_likes=1 id=1
          android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: contacto_likes.id (code 1555)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343) ...
```

Depurando pude ver que en la línea en que me da la excepción es esta:

```
db.insert(ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT, null, contentValues);
```

Entonces no se cuál sea mi error al insertar el like.

Esta es mi clase BaseDatos (la que hereda de SQLiteOpenHelper):

```
public class BaseDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;

    public BaseDatos(Context context) {
        super(context, ConstantesBaseDatos.DATABASE_NAME, null, ConstantesBaseDatos.DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String queryCrearTablaContacto = "CREATE TABLE " + ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" +
                ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_CONTACTS_ID       + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_CONTACTS_NOMBRE   + " TEXT, " +
                ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_CONTACTS_TELEFONO + " TEXT, " +
                ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_CONTACTS_EMAIL    + " TEXT, " +
                ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_CONTACTS_FOTO     + " INTEGER" +
                ")";

        String queryCrearTablaLikesContacto = "CREATE TABLE " + ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT + "(" +
                ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT_ID             + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT_ID_CONTACTO    + " INTEGER, " +
                ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT_NUMERO_LIKES   + " INTEGER, " +
                "FOREIGN KEY (" + ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT_ID_CONTACTO + ") " +
                "REFERENCES " + ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_CONTACTS + " (" + ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_CONTACTS_ID + ")" +
                ")";

        db.execSQL(queryCrearTablaContacto);
        db.execSQL(queryCrearTablaLikesContacto);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_CONTACTS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public ArrayList<Contacto> obtenerTodosLosContactos() {
        ArrayList<Contacto> contactos = new ArrayList<>();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor registros = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        while (registros.moveToNext()) {
            Contacto contactoActual = new Contacto();

            contactoActual.setId(registros.getInt(0));
            contactoActual.setNombre(registros.getString(1));
            contactoActual.setTelefono(registros.getString(2));
            contactoActual.setEmail(registros.getString(3));
            contactoActual.setFoto(registros.getInt(4));

            contactos.add(contactoActual);
        }

        db.close();

        return contactos;
    }

    public void insertarContacto(ContentValues contentValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);

        db.close();
    }

    public void insertarLikeContacto(ContentValues contentValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT, null, contentValues);

        db.close();
    }

    public int obtenerLikesContacto(Contacto contacto) {
        int likes = 0;

        String query = "SELECT COUNT(" + ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT_NUMERO_LIKES + ")" +
                " FROM " + ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT +
                " WHERE " + ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT_ID_CONTACTO + "=" + contacto.getId();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor registros = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (registros.moveToNext()) {
            likes = registros.getInt(0);
        }

        db.close();

        return likes;
    }
}
```

Y estos son los métodos para manejar el asunto de agregar un like en mi clase ConstructorContactos que usé como intermediaria:

```
public void darLikeContacto(Contacto contacto) {
    BaseDatos bd = new BaseDatos(context);

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT_ID, contacto.getId());
    contentValues.put(ConstantesBaseDatos.TABLE_LIKES_CONTACT_NUMERO_LIKES, LIKE);

    bd.insertarLikeContacto(contentValues);
}

public int obtenerLikesContacto(Contacto contacto) {
    BaseDatos db = new BaseDatos(context);
    return db.obtenerLikesContacto(contacto);
}
```

Entonces no se qué esté causando el error que al dar like por segunda vez en lugar de insertarlo y devolver la suma me lance la excepción. Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que alcanzo entender de tu código, el error se encuentra en que en la tabla donde insertas no se puede repetir la llave primaria, en este caso el id, por lo tanto si deseas hacer una nueva inserción con el mismo id sale ese error, seria bueno que agregaras el código completo que usas para tu base de datos y así poder ayudarte mejor a encontrar una solución.

Comment: Buena observación, lo mas importante serian los `CREATE` statements, sin embargo sería mejor de comentarlo en la pregunta y esperar con la respuesta hasta que la pregunta esta mejorada. :)

Comment: Hola, soy nuevo en esto y la verdad no estaba muy seguro de lo que hacía, pero revisé y en efecto estaba ocupando la llave primaria, me confundí con los nombres que puse, actualizo la pregunta por si puede servirle de ayuda a alguien, muchas gracias.